# Deleting file from Firebase Storage using URL

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to delete a file from Firebase Storage using the files URL.
My issue is that the getReferenceFromUrl() can not be resolved.

Sample code here:

```
 StorageReference mStorageRef;
    String storageurl = "http:sample"
    mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        StorageReference ref2 = mStorageRef.getReferenceFromUrl(storageurl);
        ref2.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                // File deleted successfully
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "file deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: deleted file");
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: did not delete file");
            }
        });
```

Comment: post error log here

Comment: Error:(358, 44) error: cannot find symbol method getReferenceFromUrl(String)

Comment: try mStorageRef.child(sorageurl); instead of mStorageRef.getReferenceFromUrl(sorageurl);

Comment: sadly that throws an error as well. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The storage Uri could not be parsed.
                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(Unknown Source)

Comment: Can you show how you include the Firebase SDK in your project? e.g. if this is an Android project, edit the question to include the relevant lines from your build.gradle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this I have tried this and its working

```
 String storageUrl = "Chat-Images/1498804025000.png";
 StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(storageUrl);
 storageReference.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
           // File deleted successfully
           Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: deleted file");
      }
      }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
      @Override
      public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: did not delete file");
         }
      });
```

Answer (score 13):

```
 StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/***********************-5fac-45b6-bbda-ed4e8a3a62ab");
 storageReference.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() { 
    @Override 
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        // File deleted successfully 
        Log.e("firebasestorage", "onSuccess: deleted file");
    } 
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred! 
        Log.e("firebasestorage", "onFailure: did not delete file");
    } 
});
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution but it does not work, files do not get deleted that way, especially that there is an appended token to the url

Answer (score 8):

**Snippet for Delete file from Firebase Storage Using URL:**

```
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/***********************-5fac-45b6-bbda-ed4e8a3a62ab");
storageReference.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        // File deleted
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Error
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is `getStorage()` to be able to use `getReferenceFromUrl()`,

eg:

```
FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getStorage().getReferenceFromUrl(fileURL);
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using kotlin, this is the code:

```
        val storageReference: StorageReference =            FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(urifinal) //urifinal is a String variable with the url
        storageReference.delete().addOnSuccessListener {
            //File deleted
            Log.d("storage", "Done")
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            //failed to delete
            Log.d("storage", "error while deleting")
        }
```