# Delete file from firebase using files download URI?

Tags: android, file, firebase, firebase-storage

How to delete file from firebase storage?
I'm having files only download URI(String), how can I delete file from fire-base storage?
I tried to parse my download string to uri and tried to reference my storage reference to that uri, but it didn't worked

```
private void image_delete(int i){
         for(;i<=3;i++){
            image_path[i]=image_path[i+1];
            if(image_path[i+1]==null)
                img[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.camera);
            else
            Picasso.get().load(image_path[i+1]).into(img[i]);
            image_path[i]=image_path[i+1];
            img[i+1].setImageResource(R.drawable.camera);
            if(image_path[i+1]==null)
                break;
        }
        if(i!=4)
        image_body[i+1].setVisibility(View.GONE);
        image_path[i]=null;
        storageReference=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        storageReference.child("Pets").child(image_path[i].substring(image_path[i].indexOf("/Pets")+4,image_path[i].length()));
        storageReference.delete();
        upload_status.setText("");
    }
```

Comment: Please paste the code as text into your question then highlight and press Ctrl+K this allows us to copy and paste your code into our IDEs and help identify the problem. Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to know what code you need to include

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete any file from **Firebase** Storage using **URL**:

```
 String url= "Chat-Images/1498804025000.png";

 StorageReference storageReference = 
 FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(url);

 storageReference.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
           Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: deleted file successfully");
      }
      }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {

      @Override
      public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: File is not delete!");
         }
      });
```

Orginal answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45103937/9093630

Comment: but im not having this sort of uri,
my uri is in format "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/abcd.appspot.com/o/Pets%2FMon+Oct+01+16%3A06%3A00+GMT%2B08%3A00+2018?alt=media&token=54718536-3503-4421-aad0-c314f7bb6f06"

Comment: actually while uploading i save file url by saving its downloadable url, and then load image from firebase using picasso by passing file's downloadable url

Comment: Does spaces in name effect address??

Comment: You can save url downloadable in Firebase database during Uploading file and use it in process download like code above